# KNN with RFECV returns: "The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to apply RFECV on KNeighborsClassifier to eliminate insignificant features. In order to make the issue repeatable, here is an example with iris data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
iris = load_iris()
y = iris.target
X = iris.data
estimator = KNeighborsClassifier()
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
```

which results in the following error massage:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-19f0f2f0f0e7> in <module>()
      7 estimator = KNeighborsClassifier()
      8 selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
----> 9 selector.fit(X, y)

C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in fit(self, X, y)
    422                       verbose=self.verbose - 1)
    423 
--> 424             rfe._fit(X_train, y_train, lambda estimator, features:
    425                      _score(estimator, X_test[:, features], y_test, scorer))
    426             scores.append(np.array(rfe.scores_[::-1]).reshape(1, -1))

C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in _fit(self, X, y, step_score)
    180                 coefs = estimator.feature_importances_
    181             else:
--> 182                 raise RuntimeError('The classifier does not expose '
    183                                    '"coef_" or "feature_importances_" '
    184                                    'attributes')

RuntimeError: The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes
```

If I change the classifier to a SVC as:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
iris = load_iris()
y = iris.target
X = iris.data
estimator = SVC(kernel="linear")
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
```

it would work fine. Any suggestions on how to address the issue?

**NOTE:** I updated Anaconda yesterday which also updated the sklearn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error is pretty self explanatory - knn does not provide logic to do feature selection. You cannot use it (sklearn's implementation) to achieve such goal, unless you define your own measure of feature importance for KNN. As far as I know - there is no such general object, and so - scikit-learn does not implement it. SVM on the other hand, like every linear model - provides such information.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a partial solution from the `mlxtend` library:

http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/feature_selection/SequentialFeatureSelector/

see https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend

As for Scikit-learn see:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6920