# RFECV machine learning feature selection taking far too long Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, rfe

I am relatively new to SKLearn and have a question about Feature Selection.

I am trying to build an SVM model, with my data having around 30 features all of about 10k data points, and I'm currently trying to eliminate as many useless features as I can. I have first dropped features that are highly correlated to other features, and now want to use RFECV to optimize the remaining ones.

To begin with, I found this code on the sklearn website, I have a couple of issues with it and wondered if anyone could help.

```
X = df.drop(['label'], axis=1)
y = df['label']

rfe = RFECV(SVR(kernel='linear'), step=1, scoring='accuracy')
rfe.fit(X, y)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

Firstly, if I run this as it is it takes forever to run, I've left it for ages and I haven't actually managed to get it to complete yet. However, if I remove `kernel='linear'` it runs reasonably quickly, but then produces an error message, which appears to come from `rfe.fit(X, y)`:

`RuntimeError: The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes`

I've cut my features down to about 10, just to see if I can speed things up as a test, and have also played around with the `step` variable, but with the `kernel='linear'` variable in there nothing seems to help speed it up, it just runs for hours without doing anything. All I want is a list of features to use using the RFECV method. Does anyone have any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to speed things up?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KNN with RFECV returns: "The classifier does not expose "coef\_" or "feature\_importances\_" attributes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780139/knn-with-rfecv-returns-the-classifier-does-not-expose-coef-or-feature-impo)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780139/knn-with-rfecv-returns-the-classifier-does-not-expose-coef-or-feature-impo

Answer (score 4):

1. The reason it runs quickly when you remove "kernel='linear'", is because it fails quickly.
2. Only SVR(kernel='linear') returns a coef_ that can be used by RFECV. If you use any other kernel, no coef_ is returned thus RFECV cannot work with it.
3. By setting "step=1", you're forcing RFECV(SVR(kernel='linear'), step=1, scoring='accuracy') to fit on all n features, exclude the one with the lowest coefficient, fit again on n-1 features, exclude the one with the lowest coefficient again, etc.
   This is time consuming.

Try this to speed up the process:

```
RFECV(SVR(kernel='linear'), step=5, scoring='accuracy', min_features_to_select = 10)
```

This should be significantly faster. Adjust "step" and "min_features_to_select" to your specific needs.

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your answer, unfortunately nothing seems to be working. I reduced the feature columns to 8 in the end, and set the step to 3, with min_features_to_select to 5, which I assume means it only has to do the whole process once and just drop the bottom 3, but my machine still refuses to complete the process, it just sits there running with the fan on full blast. My guess is something is very wrong with my machine, just not sure what.

Answer (score 3):

SVR models work better with scaled/normalized data. Try this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X = df.drop(['label'], axis=1)
X_norm = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X)
y = df['label']

rfe = RFECV(SVR(kernel='linear'), step=1, scoring='accuracy')
rfe.fit(X_norm, y)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

This should speed things up quite a bit from my personal experience.

Alternatively, I believe you can also use standard scaler for scaling your features: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html